# How to check surrounding of each cell in a 2D boolean array grid?

Tags: java, grid, cell

I have a for loop that prints either O or - depending on if the value in a 2D boolean array called 'grid' is true or false, like so:

```
    boolean[][] grid = new boolean[10][10];
    grid[1][1] = true;
    grid[2][2] = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
            if (grid[i][j] == true){
                System.out.print("O");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I'm wondering how I can, later in the program, successfully check (and then print) how many O's (if any) surround each cell of the grid.

Here is my attempt:

```
    int countO = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++){
            if (grid[i - 1][j - 1] == true){
                countO++;
            }
            if (grid[i - 1][j + 1] == true){
                countO++;
            }
            if (grid[i + 1][j + 1] == true){
                countO++;
            }
            if (grid[i + 1][j - 1] == true){
                countO++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(countO);
```

but I can't even successfully test it without getting errors.

Comment: so thats correct just first check if its valid and then do those if statements. So bounds check `i`and `j`  with the length and if it goes outside of the length or is `negative` then simply skip over that check

Comment: Will do! Thank you. Glad to hear my logic is in the right place.